# Swift: Parsing Array of object

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a `Contact` object which can have and array of `Address` objects.

```
class Contact {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var middleName: String = ""
    var id: Int = -1
    var addresses: Array<Address> = []
```

How would I initialize each `Address` object while fetching it from `json` dictionary?

```
init(json: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

        if let line1 = json["streetLine"] as? String {
            self.streetLine1 = line1
        }
        if let city = json["city"] as? String {
            self.city = city
        }
        if let state = json["state"] as? String {
            self.state = state
        }
        if let zip = json["zip"] as? Int {
            self.zip = zip
        }
```

Tried doing like this:

```
if let addressMap = json["addresses"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>> {
            for address as? Address in addressMap {
                addresses.append(address)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let dictionaryArray = json["addresses"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Anyobject?>> 
    for address in dictionaryArray {
        var address = Address(json: address)
        addresses.append(address)
    }
}
```

So you get your list of Dictionarys from your json, loop through them and then use your init function to inject the data into your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
addresses = (json["addresses"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>>)?.map{Address(json: $0)}
```